# Finding the row in a MySQL DB, which has the most words in common with a given string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm looking to make a call, where I need to make a search in a column (string), and count how many words that entry has in common with a provided string.

I've been looking into LCS, but I doesn't really suit me, as I don't need to match an actual subsequence, but I need to find the (top 4) rows, which has the most words in common with the provided string, in arbitrary order.

I've jiggled down some pseudo code, to help explain the gist of it:

```
query[] = array of keywords
counter[] = map of rowid => counter

do {
  keywords[]  = (select tags from i´th row from db).explode(" ")

  foreach(word in query[]) {
    foreach(tag in keywords[]) {
      if(word == tag) {
        counter(rowid, count++)
      }
    }
  }
  i++
} while(i <= number_of_rows)

sorted_counter = sort_array_by_value(counter)
row1 = counter[0]
row2 = counter[1]
row3 = counter[2]
row4 = counter[3]
```

Any help would be appreciated. It can be in SQL or PHP, and run-time isn't really a big factor.

edit: clarification

Comment: What is your storage engine and what is your column type?

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016804/how-to-sort-mysql-fulltext-search-results-by-relevancy

Comment: Take a look to the reference manual; specifically [Full-text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: @Victory InnoDB and type is text

BratAnon & Barranka - I'll check out the links, thanks.