# Laravel 4 (Eloquent ORM / Query Builder) how to sort keyword search based on most matches

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder, keyword-search

I have the following keyword search implemented in Laravel 4:

```
// Search by keyword(s)
if(Input::get('keyword'))
    {
    $search = Input::get('keyword');
    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

    $fields = array(
        'resources.name',
        'resources.description',
        'resources.website',
        'resources.additional_info');

    $query->where(function($query) use ($searchTerms, $fields) {
        foreach ($searchTerms as $term)
        {
            foreach ($fields as $field)
            {
                $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%'. $term .'%');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem:
Let's say I have two resources in my table, one with the name `foo`, one with the name `bar`, and one with the name `foo bar`. They were created and put into my table in that order. Now, if I search for "foo bar", the first two results I get will be `foo` and `bar` (because they are fist in my table to match either foo or bar), and my third result will be `foo bar`. How can I make this search so it orders the results based on the number of keywords which are matched? So `foo bar` will be the first result.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement this using a [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) search.  You don't specify which database engine you're using, so I'll give a MySQL example.

First, you need to enable full-text indexing on the fields you want to search.

```
ALTER TABLE resources ADD FULLTEXT search (name,description,website,additional_info);
```

Then, you need to end up with something like the following in your query:

```
SELECT
    *, MATCH(name,description,website,additional_info) AGAINST(SEARCH_TERMS) AS score
WHERE
    MATCH(name,description,website,additional_info) AGAINST(SEARCH_TERMS)
```

I would do that in the Laravel Query Builder using something like this (untested):

```
if(Input::get('keyword'))
{
    $search = Input::get('keyword');
    $searchTerms = explode(' ', $search);

    $fields = array(
        '`resources.name`',
        '`resources.description`',
        '`resources.website`',
        '`resources.additional_info`'
    );

    $fields_str = implode(',', $fields);
    $query->whereRaw("match ($fields_str) against (? in boolean mode)")
    $query->addSelect(DB::raw("match ($fields_str) against (? in boolean mode)")
    // Need to bind twice because there are two question marks...
    $query->setBindings(array($searchTerms, $searchTerms))
}
```

Depending on your search, you may or may not actually need `in boolean mode`, or you may want to specify a different mode.  See the MySQL manual for details.

---

**NOTE**: Most relational database engines aren't really that good at search; it's just not what they were originally designed to do.  If you find that your search needs are getting more complicated than this simple example, you should look into running a search server like Lucene, Sphinx, Elasticsearch, or Solr

(For more info, see http://blog.oneiroi.co.uk/mysql/php/mysql-full-text-search-with-percentage-scoring/ and http://www.mullie.eu/mysql-as-a-search-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following solution for my search:

```
if(Input::get('keyword')) {
    $search = Input::get('keyword');
    $query->whereRaw("MATCH(resources.name, resources.description, resources.website, resources.additional_info) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 
        array($search)
    );
}
```

I came upon this solution by reading through the following pages:

[How to sort MYSQL fulltext search results by relevancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016804/how-to-sort-mysql-fulltext-search-results-by-relevancy)

http://creative-punch.net/2013/12/implementing-laravel-4-full-text-search/

I upgraded to MySQL 5.6 so I could add fulltext indexes to my InnoDB tables. I had to add the fulltext indexes to all the fields I wanted to run `MATCH` on, in the order that I specified in the `whereRaw` statement.