# mysql php result list using zipcode

Tags: mysql

I've restaurant table with zipcode. I've searched with zipcode '2600'. so I need to display the result based on searched zipcode and then list other zipcode.

```
resid   resname zipcode
1   Res1    2500
2   Res2    2505
3   Res3    2600
4   Res4    2510
5   Res5    2600
6   Res6    2610
7   Res7    2700
```

I need to list the output like below....

```
resid   resname zipcode
3   Res3    2600
5   Res5    2600
1   Res1    2500
2   Res2    2505
4   Res4    2510
6   Res6    2610
7   Res7    2700
```

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016804/how-to-sort-mysql-fulltext-search-results-by-relevancy

Answer (score 3):

You have to use Mysql function [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY FIELD(zipcode, 2600) DESC
```

[SQL Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c28f2/4)

Comment: Adding a second ORDER BY parameter would also sort the other rows. `ORDER BY FIELD(zipcode, 2600) DESC, zipcode`

Answer (score -2):

Above query is correct except it gives the result at last.Add desc will give correct result.

SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY FIELD(zipcode, 2600)  desc